# Python mxTextTools ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python

I'm running python 2.7 on windows 7 and trying to get SimpleParse to work. This means I need mxTextTools, which I downloaded from . But when I try to import mx.TextTools, I get an ImportError saying it can't load a DLL (its nice that it doesn't tell me *which* one). Here is all the code needed to get the error to come up:

```
from mx.TextTools import TextTools
```

I get the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\...\code\PYTHON\parsemovies 2.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mx.TextTools import TextTools
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mx\TextTools\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from TextTools import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mx\TextTools\TextTools.py", line 13, in <module>
    from mxTextTools import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mx\TextTools\mxTextTools\__init__.py", line 8, in <modul
e>
    from mxTextTools import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried adding my python directory and my python DLLs directory to my PATH env variable. I restarted my computer too. Anyone have any ideas whats going on?

Comment: You forgot the mxTextTools link :)

Comment: You mean this: http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxTextTools/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made the same mistake that I made, which was that when I downloaded eGenix mx Base, I didn't notice the drop down box for selecting the appropriate version of Python, and ended up installing the wrong version.